# Why won't my WPF application close properly after it displays a WinForms dialog?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, visual-studio-2010, dialog

I am using a 3rd party WinForms Login Dialog in my WPF app, and for some reason this is making my WPF application not close correctly when debugging.

If I exit the winforms login dialog prior to logging in, the application closes correctly, however if I login successfully and launch the WPF window, exiting the window does not shut down the application.

I put a breakpoint in the `OnExit` method of `App` and it never gets called. I overwrote the `OnClosing` method of my main window, and that does get called but even calling `Application.Current.ShutDown()` doesn't exit the application correctly. I have also tried setting my App's `ShutdownMode` to `OnExplicitShutdown` and `OnMainWindowClose` and neither of those shut it down.

The only hint I have is the following appears in the Debug window, but I have no idea what it's trying to tell me.

```
The thread 'vshost.RunParkingWindow' (0xf74) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread <No Name> (0x1b58) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

This behavior only occurs when running in Debug mode in Visual Studio. Running the app without debugging closes the app correctly.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what could be causing this behavior?

**Edit**

The WinForms login dialog is not a traditional login dialog with a `Show()` or `Close()` method, it's a static class that only has a `Login()` and `Logout()` method.

It's used by someething like this:

```
if (CompanyNamespace.ApplicationName.Login())
{
    var shell = new ShellView();
    var context = new ShellViewModel();
    shell.DataContext = context;
    shell.Show();

    // When the Shell Window gets closed, the debugger doesn't stop
}
else
{
    Application.Current.Shutdown(); // Works fine
}
```

Comment: can you show the way you show the login dialog and after login the way you open the main window?

Comment: @Davide I added some sample code

Comment: @Rachel : btw, have you checked whether Application.Current.MainWindow is set? It could be that it is null due to first opened window was WinForms dialog

Comment: @sllev `Application.Current.MainWindow` is set to my Shell

Comment: @Rachel: "a 3rd party WinForms Login Dialog in my WPF app". Could you elaborate a bit on this aspect? Which vendor and control are you using? Also, the 'why' isn't clear either.

Comment: @bic I found a solution, although I'm waiting for the user to update their answer to accept it. As to the why, I only want authorized users to use this application and don't want to maintain a 2nd set of users/permissions, and I am using some of their 3rd party controls which require the static Login to succeed to initialize the internal connection string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>this sounds stupid, but have you tried to call winformsLoginDialog.Close(); in the onClosing method of your main window? I suspect the winforms login dialog still has a thread running, and/or the form may have been hidden instead of closed.</strike>

You could try `System.Environment.Exit(0)`

Comment: I don't really have a close method... it's a closed 3rd party static dialog so all I really have to call is `Login()` and `Logout()`, and the same behavior still occurs after calling `Logout()`

Comment: You could try System.Environment.Exit(0);

Comment: <3 Thanks! Change your answer to that and I'll accept it. That works to close whatever thread is open in the WinForms dialog

Comment: I suspect the Winform dialog is maintaining its own message loop, preventing the application from closing.  I'd look to find a way to dispose of that window. Using System.Environment.Exit is a lot like using dynamite to make a door because you didn't want to follow the exit signs.

Comment: @Bahri I'd be happy to find another way, but unfortunately this isn't my code and the code provided doesn't have an existing Close or Dispose method. Since this behavior only occurs in debug mode, the best I can do is set it up so I only call `Environment.Exit` if I'm debugging

Comment: I have to downvote this purely for future visitors to SO. This is akin to terminating a process and doesn't address the actual problem described.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the default shutdown mode is

```
ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnLastWindowClose
```

If the application is not shutting down then there are still windows open. Check the Application.Current.Windows collection in the debugger to find the offending window.

So its best, in my opinion, to use

```
ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnMainWindowClose;
```

And then make sure to set the following

```
Application.Current.MainWindow= MyWindow; // Shell etc.
```

Comment: The same behavior still occurs. Also, `Application.Current.Windows` only has one window, which is the Shell.

Comment: @Rachel: And you set the Application.Current.MainWindow = Shell; ?

Comment: It is set to the Shell automatically, however even if I explicitly set it, yes the same behavior occurs