# How does Ninject 3 affect object lifetime?

Tags: c#, ninject

Before I had refactored my project for DI with Ninject, I had a simple test class with a simple method:

```
    public void TestImport()
    {
        var functionality = new ImportFunctionality();
        functionality.Execute();
    }
```

When I ran this "app" (merely a sandbox WPF client app for integration testing my library), I had the "main" window showing up and clicking a button on that window called this `TestImport` method, which executed and then I could test and debug my code, and when then main window was closed, the app died right there and VS would exit debug mode. Normal stuff.

Then I refactored the whole thing and implemented dependency injection with Ninject, factories and interfaces all over the code; the `TestImport` method now looks like this:

```
    public void TestImport()
    {
        using (var kernel = new StandardKernel())
        {
            kernel.Load<SecurityNinjectModule>();
            kernel.Load<HelpersNinjectModule>();
            kernel.Load<ImportFunctionalityNinjectModule>();

            var functionality = kernel.Get<IImportFunctionality>();
            functionality.Execute();
        }
    }
```

Now when I run the WPF sandbox/test app, everything works and that's great, except when the "main" window gets closed, *the application does not exit anymore and Visual Studio remains in debug mode*. I added the call to `Dispose()` in the hope to fix it, but no luck; wrapping it in a `using` block doesn't fix it either.

If I run the sandbox *without* clicking the button to run the `TestImport` method, and then close the main window, the app shuts down properly.

This leads me to the Ninject kernel object. Could it be holding on to its resources somehow despite the `Dispose()` call? Then how do I properly shut down an application that's running Ninject 3.0?

**EDIT**
If I bring up the debug/windows/threads window, I see all instantiated threads either sleeping or "in a sleep, wait, or join", if not "not available"; a thread by the name of `.NET System Events` is sleeping, waiting or joining; the main thread is "managed to native transition" as well as a thread called `vshost.RunParkingWindow` - and this is where I got to [Why won't my WPF application close properly after it displays a WinForms dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349068/why-wont-my-wpf-application-close-property-after-it-displays-a-winforms-dialog). The answer seems to work given it is accepted, but as  @BahriGungor says "*Using System.Environment.Exit is a lot like using dynamite to make a door because you didn't want to follow the exit signs*". And it doesn't say *why this is happening*.

The interesting thing is, it doesn't happen consistently: sometimes I can break and step through code and when I "F5" to resume, and then close the main window, it does shut down properly. What's going on?

**EDIT 2**
The functionality brings up a `FileDialog`, and if that dialog doesn't return an Excel workbook's filename, the import window doesn't show up. I've narrowed it down to this:

- If the import view is shown, no matter how it is closed after closing the main app window VS will properly exit debug mode.
- If the import view is not shown (i.e. the `FileDialog` doesn't return anything editable) then VS **will not** exit debug mode after closing the main app window.

Comment: Note: The import view is located in another assembly and is accessed by its interface and injected by the kernel as specified in the NinjectModules. FileDialog is just `Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog` and was there well before Ninject was introduced in the project. Am I misusing something?

Comment: There's a possibility that I might not be properly disposing of disposable objects in `IImportFunctionality` and everything that comes with it. I'll hunt them down and see if I might have simply not noticed this behavior before the refactoring - in which case Ninject has nothing to do with my issue.

Comment: Bottom line is Ninject is just a library you call - right now it and you have got the system into a mess. Just debug it and don't assume Ninject does anything of consequence - it doesnt

Comment: First, I'm concerned about your comment of "factories and interfaces all over the code".  In general you should never need to create factories with Ninject, and you shouldn't have them or Interfaces "all over the place".  You don't mention what your various modules do either.

Comment: One other thing I didnt like from your code, but isnt necessarily a direct cause of your problem is that your `TestImport` method mixes one-time Kernel initialization code with composition/execution and the teardown - it's not clear whether you reuse the instance or ever can end up double-initializing the Kernel

Comment: @MystereMan One of the factories takes a connection string and and enum that determines the type of the model that will be created, for instance. I'm quite green with DI and I'll dig deeper into your statement about not needing any factories with Ninject. Interfaces are all under a ".Abstract" namespace and well organized, I meant I have one for pretty much everything. @ RubenBartelink I don't intend to be reusing the kernel, I'll edit the code to better show intent, but I'm not clear about what you mean, this isn't production code it's just a sandbox app to test things out. How should I init?

Comment: I didn't say you don't need factories, i'm saying in general.  There are always edge cases where a factory may be needed, but to have them "all over the place" seems excessive.  Ninject is expressive enough that factories are seldom needed and only in more advanced uses.  If you're using them for simple things then you're doing something wrong, but since you haven't shown us any of that code.. we have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DI should have a [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) where 99% of your DI code lives. Factories should be the 1% case of dependency injection. For [WPF that is the onStartup method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079530/where-is-the-composition-root-in-a-wpf-mdi-application).

Also I don't see anywhere in your code where you specify a lifetime management part of DI.  If you aren't specifying a lifetime management aka `Bind<Samurai>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();` then you may be getting no lifetime management and no disposal. [Here's the information on scopes for ninject](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes).

You say you added a call to dispose somewhere along the way, but if you have event listeners set up without weak references there can be [a memory leak](http://diditwith.net/2007/03/23/SolvingTheProblemWithEventsWeakEventHandlers.aspx) leading to a lack of disposal.

Finally did you follow the other answer on your linked `System.Environment.Exit` question?
**Check the Application.Current.Windows collection in the debugger to find the offending window.** https://stackoverflow.com/a/7349650/57883

Have you tried using other win forms dialogs or just the one to see if it is reproducable?

Comment: The project being a class library, I don't have a "onStartup" method. However I ended up putting all of the DI within a "MyApp" class which client code instantiates at startup (might eventually refactor that into specialized NinjectModules), so I now have a composition root! Thing is, the issue *magically* disappeared after I refactored and had the "IFunctionality" instances injected into a container "module" object that the "MyApp" class controls... plus I found some event listeners that never were un-registered! So I'll mark this as the answer, thanks for taking the time!

Comment: And +1 for a very detailed answer!